# JQuery ParseJson - bad control character literal error

Tags: jquery

I know this is a silly problem. 
I am getting error in this code :

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"Particulars":"CHEQUE NO. 010567 DATED 19/4/2013 BRANCH  FROM INSTRUMENTS P LTD_C08015186 AGST MHX217    9554    17/04/2013  30633"}');
```

Error is : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal

It seems there is a line feed in the string. Since it is invisible I cannot replace it.
JSONLint also throws error.

How to get around with this invisible control character?

Comment: Well, you can replace anything thats not a visible character using Regex.

Comment: how did you get this error? it is okay here http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrvf/

Comment: If you paste the entire string as is, there is an invisible characater. Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Qjrvf/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh yes techfoobar you are right.

Invisible character is Tab.

This did it :

.replace(/\s+/g,"")

Thanks...

Comment: But this will also remove all your spaces as well.